# My site got hacked and he left behind an encrypted filed

Tags: wordpress, encryption

This morning I logged onto my website and shockingly I found that it just spit out error messages and some kind of upload form was displayed. A form that basically uploads a file onto my server.

I logged into my server and had a look at the access log. It seems he accessed the function file of my wordpress theme, fully deleted the original and created an upload form out of it.
With that upload form he then uploaded the following file.

Edit: I had to copy the code to hastebin, it was too big to be posted here.

http://hastebin.com/itedinefiz.php

He named the file web-info.php. I did not run the file because I am afraid that it might do some harmful things to my site.

Could anyone tell me what this file does?

Anyway, I have restored the functions.php file of my wordpress theme and deleted that web-info.php file form the server and now it seems that the website is running again.

Oh and my guess he gained access to my website because my login credentials were very easy... very stupid of me :(

Comment: I would put the site offline, backup its data if possible, and re-install everything. You can't know for sure what has been compromised.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will do that. Any chance you would know what that file does that he uploaded? I ran it in my local MAMP server, and it seems to be a password form, but looking at the HTML source, it doesn't seem to be submitting it to anywhere.

Im curious on what that file does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a bit research this what I came up with.

The malicious file that I have posted above, was encoded using eval(gzinflate(base64_decode));

Thanks to http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/ I was able to decoded it, here is the raw PHP file that the hacker left behind:

http://pastebin.com/fAEQn2j7

I ran the file on my local machine, holy crap! It's a full on rootkit. It has massive interface that covers pretty much anything to take over the entire server. It seems to let you browser the entire files on the server, run sql code, run php code, brutforce options, network option and so on.

I think the safest it to cancel the entire VPS that I am renting from Bluehost, a normal wordpress deinstallation won't do any good.